# Overriding Play 2.1 Checkbox Form Helper for Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.1

I want to show an HTML checkbox followed by the label to the right.

I followed [Pere Villega's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206961/is-it-possible-to-override-form-helpers), and modified the Play 2.1-SNAPSHOT version of `views.helper.checkbox.scala` as`views.helper.twitterCheckbox.scala`. My project uses the version of Twitter Bootstrap provided by [Webjars](http://www.jamesward.com/2012/04/25/introducing-webjars-web-libraries-as-managed-dependencies):

```
@**
 * Generate an HTML input checkbox for Twitter Bootstrap.
 *
 * Example:
 * {{{
 * @checkbox(field = myForm("done"))
 * }}}
 *
 * @param field The form field.
 * @param args Set of extra HTML attributes ('''id''' and '''label''' are 2 special arguments).
 * @param handler The field constructor.
 *@
@(field: play.api.data.Field, args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@boxValue = @{ args.toMap.get('value).getOrElse("true") }

@input(field, args:_*) { (id, name, value, htmlArgs) =>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="@name" value="@boxValue" @(
      if(value == Some(boxValue)) "checked" else "") @toHtmlArgs(htmlArgs.filterKeys(_ == 'value)) />
    @args.toMap.get('_text)
  </label>
}
```

I used the form helper like this:

```
@import helper._
@form(action = courseName.map(routes.CoursesController.update(_)).getOrElse(routes.CoursesController.save()),
               args = 'class -> "form-horizontal") {
  <div class="span3">
    <p><b>@{if (allCourses.size>0) "" else "No "}Prerequisite Courses</b></p>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        @allCourses.map { course =>
          @twitterCheckbox(field = editCourseForm(course.name))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

But I get output like this, which causes the checkbox to be on a different line then the label. The output has been formatted for readability - note the `dl` and `dd` tags:

```
<form action="/courses/admin" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="span3">
  <p><b>Prerequisite Courses</b></p>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <dl class=" " id="skus_field">
        <dt><label for="skus">skus</label></dt>
        <dd>
          <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="skus" value="true"   />
          </label>
        </dd>
       </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Seems like there is some sort of implicit behavior I am unaware of. How can I generate something like the following instead, or at least some output that will give the desired result?

```
<form action="/courses/admin" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="span3">
  <p><b>Prerequisite Courses</b></p>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <label class="checkbox">
        <input name="skues" type="checkbox" value="true"> sku1
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem: the checkbox were not well formatted for TwitterBootstrap CSS.

So I had to define my own checkbox helper (in order to add the `<label>` tag):

File path:

`app\views\helper\checkbox2.scala.html`

Content:

```
@(field: play.api.data.Field, args: (Symbol,Any)*)(implicit handler: FieldConstructor, lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

<label class="checkbox">
    @checkbox(field, args:_*)
</label>
```

Then, I have redefined my fields constructor template to match Twitter Bootstrap:

File path:

`app\views\helper\bootstrapInput.scala.html`

Content:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="control-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="controls">
        @elements.input
        @if(!elements.errors.isEmpty) {
            <span class="help-inline alert alert-error">@elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span>
        }
        <span class="help-block">@elements.infos(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I have created a field constructor with an impicit call to the template above:

File path:

`app\controllers\helpers\BootstrapHelper.scala`

Content:

```
package controllers.helpers

import views.html.helper.FieldConstructor

object BootstrapHelper {
  implicit val myFields = FieldConstructor(views.html.helper.bootstrapInput.f)
}
```

And finally, I just import it in my "normal" views:

```
@import helper._
@import helpers.BootstrapHelper._
```

This is exactly was is written in the doc (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaFormHelpers) and it works out finely.

At the end, all my inputs were correctly displayed with the Twitter Bootstrap and the checkbox as well.

Hope this helps

**EDIT** as asked by Mike Slinn, I just added files path and a few details about the implicit call of the field constructor. However, the file names do not really matter here and variants are possible to make the implicit call (see the doc).

Comment: teemoo, would you like to show the names of your files? It would help others try out your code

Comment: @MikeSlinn file names added, as suggested, and implicit call detailed as well. I hope you'll be able to make it work.

Comment: File names useful, thank you. Sometimes obvious once you've seen them, but makes it clear.