# play framework bind form field to checkbox

Tags: data-binding, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, playframework-2.0

How can I bind a field in myForm called "isMarried" to the checkbox control in view? I want this binding bi-directional. I am using bootstrap switch from https://github.com/nostalgiaz/bootstrap-switch

```
@(myForm: Form[_])
@helper.form(action = controllers.index.submit, 'id -> "myForm") {

<fieldset>
<legend>General information</legend>
<div class="twipsies well">
   <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="isMarried">Married</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="switch switch-small" tabindex="0" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No" data-off="warning">
                <input id="isMarried" name="isMarried" type="checkbox"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your question. What do you mean by "bi-directional"? And I don't know your problem correlation with bootstrap switch.

Comment: Bi-directional probably means that (a) the checkbox is initialised to the value in the domain object and (b) when the form is submitted, the domain object is updated to reflect the state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 4):

I dit not worked with checkboxes (in Pay) but I would use the checkbox helpers:

Example:

```
@checkbox(field = myForm("done"))
```

See source: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/checkbox.scala.html

If you nee to customize the HTML out to fit your needs, write your own helper / tag:

- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/JavaFormHelpers
- [Is it possible to override form helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10206961/is-it-possible-to-override-form-helpers)
- [Creating a custom field constructor in Play 2 (scala)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392302/creating-a-custom-field-constructor-in-play-2-scala)

Good luck!

Comment: FWIW, here's my working checkbox code: @checkbox(myForm("myProperty"), '_label -> Messages("my.message.code"))

Answer (score 0):

The model is:

```
/**

 * This class represent a school model 

 * @author Giovanni Alberto García

 * @version 1.0

 */

@Entity

public class School extends Model {


  @Id

  @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)

  public Long id;


  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

  public List<User> members;


  public boolean rElecCFE;

...

}
```

As you can seee rElecCFE is boolean so the view is:

```
@(schoolForm: Form[School])(schoolId: Long)

@import helper._ 

@main("Completar registro") {

<div id="edition">

  @form(action=routes.Nama.doEdit()) {
  <fieldset id="registration-electicity">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@schoolId"/>
    <legend>Electricidad</legend>
    @checkbox(schoolForm("rElecCFE"),
    '_showConstraints->false,
    '_disabled->""
    )
...
  }
</div>
}
```